# Play 2.4 Finder throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm currently having an issue with a Finder instance in Play 2.4 whereby it returns a null pointer exception when used. Here is the code trying to use it

```
public ExpressionList<ClientAuthorization> getAuthorizationQuery(String appId) {
        return ClientAuthorization.find.where().eq("app_id", appId).eq("active", 1);
    }
```

And the model class

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;


@Entity
@Table(name="client_authorization")
public class ClientAuthorization extends Model {

    public static final Finder<Long, ClientAuthorization> find = new Finder<>(ClientAuthorization.class);


    @Id
    public long clientAuthorizationId;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=45)
    public String appId;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=45)
    public String apiKey;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public boolean active;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public boolean isAdmin;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public Timestamp createdDate;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public Timestamp updatedDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void createdAt() {
        this.createdDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.updatedDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @PostPersist
    protected void updatedAt() {
        this.updatedDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }


}
```

This works fine for every model I've ever created in Play, so I'm not sure what's going on. Here is what I get

[image: NPE]

I greatly appreciate any help I can get. This is driving me crazy in an upgrade project I'm working on. The last upgrade I did went just fine, but this one is giving me problems.

Additional info: It fails on the call to where() just after the ClientAuthorization static call to find

*update*

Since it came up in a comment, this is not just a question of what a NPE is, I know that already. For some reason the finder is not initialized. However, looking at this model, and every model I've ever written, there is no reason for this to be happening.

Here is the stack trace

```
@6o9455j27 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:151) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:148) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.query(Model.java:547) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.where(Model.java:741) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
    at repositories.AuthRepository.getAuthorizationQuery(AuthRepository.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at interceptors.AuthInterceptor.call(AuthInterceptor.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[play_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nah, I know what an NPE is, I just can't figure out why it's happening in this instance. When you declare a Finder object in a Model, it should be immediately available to a calling method.

Comment: In this code `eq("app_id", appId)`, why are you using underscores? This looks more promising: `eq("appId", appId)` .

Comment: "It fails on the call to where()" `find` cannot be not null, so it cannot actually be occurring specifically on that call `find.where()`: it must be happening inside `where()` (or I've misunderstood what you mean by "on the call to where()").

Comment: @GergelyBacso, thats the name of the field in the database

Comment: @AndyTurner, you've got it. Something is happening inside where() that is throwing the NPE. I'm still investigating

Comment: @Zarathuztra posting the stack trace would help.

Comment: @AndyTurner sure, posting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody runs into a similar problem, the **config should be double-checked**. The default Model superclass does not care of it. Details about `aplication.conf` and `orm.xml` can be found here:

[EBean config](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean)

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the server name when creating the static Finder worked for me

```
Finder<String, Site> find = new Finder<String, Site>([servername], Site.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use com.avaje.ebean.Model.Find instead of Model.Finder class.

```
 public static final Find<Long,ClientAuthorization> find = new Find<Long,ClientAuthorization>(){};
```

Alternatively, you can use play.db.ebean.Model.Finder

```
public static Finder<Long,ClientAuthorization> find = new Finder<Long,ClientAuthorization>(  Long.class, ClientAuthorization.class );
```

I have not tested, please check and let me know. Please post the Exception trace for better understanding.

Comment: Model.Find is an abstract class I'm afraid. The play Finder class is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code a bit suggests that having a staticly initialized `find` object within the same class that you are building the `find` object for might be a bad idea. I would:

- first completey remove this variable from the model class and create that field somewhere else.
- or (if you must have it there) initialize that object lazily when it is first requested.

I have had a very mind-boggling issue some time ago with a static field referencing the encompassing class type and producing unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Neither of those options worked, I still get an NPE. I'm thinking there may be something wrong with how I configured the model

Comment: Or the configuration? I am just guessing to be honest... Do you have the model or its package added to an ebean server in applicaton.conf? Do you use orm.xml?

Comment: It was the config, it was missing the ebean server config. No idea why that config would be missing in the template install. If you make another answer with that I'll mark it correct

Comment: Ahh. The important is that it is fixed finally.

Comment: For sure. Definitely the weirdest thing I've run into. I thought it was built in to 2.4 (although I had suspected this was the issue at some point) but I guess I was wrong. I'll check the template install again and see if it's there. If not, might be worth opening a ticket to typesafe to tell them to include the config by default