# play 2.5 production mode ebean finder error

Tags: ebean, playframework-2.5

Play 2.5.3 production mode throws the below exception when the application tries to query data from database.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.query(Model.java:585)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.where(Model.java:779)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: Check your configuration again. This question is very similar to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940702/play-2-4-finder-throws-null-pointer-exception

Comment: There is no problem when I start the application in Dev mode. I am facing this issue in production mode. I don't have any idea what should I configure for ebean to work in production mode. I have followed the configuration as mentioned in the play documentation.

Comment: Please provide more details. For example is your call in a thread? Or is it an HTTP request? Is it something automatic or user triggered... etc..

Comment: what happened to this issue? could you solve it?